# Visting slug for 'post' post type shows 404 not archive?

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting, slug

I'm trying to get the WP default post type 'post' to show under the slug of `/news/`. I've changed the permalink structure to `/news/%postname%/` which is fine when visiting a single page, however when I simply visit /news/ without a post name attached, a 404 is issued as oppose to displaying the `archive-post.php` or event `archive.php` template.

I've checked that the permalink change has flushed the rewrite rules by visiting a single post, so I'm thinking this can't be the issue. Any ideas for resolving would be greatly appreciated, and if any more information from my side could be of help, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is correct, news has nothing to do with your structure... it's just a word...

But you can get a way around it...

you could copy archive.php and name it something like template-news.php

then edit the template-archive.php... put this at the top... just below '

```
<?php

/*
* Template Name: News
*/
```

Then add a new page in your dashboard... make sure the slug is news. Then choose the template 'News' on Templates. Then publish..